# "oc new-app" does not expose port altough the input image does

Tags: docker, openshift

I'm exploring OpenShift 3.9 and have managed to get a first container built and running with `oc new-app` and the Docker build strategy. My Dockerfile includes the command `EXPOSE 5432`.

After the rollout `oc describe istag/my_app:latest | grep ^Exposes` reports `Exposes Ports: 5432/tcp`, so that looks good: the image exposes port 5432. But `oc describe po/my_app-1-some_id | grep "^\s*Port"` reports `Port: <none>`, so overall it seems as if the port is exposed at the level of Docker, but not yet the level of Kubernetes/OpenShift.

The [OpenShift documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/application_lifecycle/new_app.html) says the following:

> The new-app command attempts to detect exposed ports in input images.
>   It uses the lowest numeric exposed port to generate a service that
>   exposes that port. In order to expose a different port, after new-app
>   has completed, simply use the oc expose command to generate additional
>   services.

Why does `oc new-app` not expose port 5432 in this situation (in fact it does not create any `service` resource either) and how can I make it do so automatically, as the input image already does and as seems possible judging from the documentation?

**UPDATE** Here is more detail on how the new application was created:

```
oc new-app ssh://my_account@my_git_server/my_path/my_repo.git
  --context-dir=my_dir --strategy=docker --name my_app
```

The Git repository contains a so far trivial `my_dir/Dockerfile`, and it in turn contains the command `EXPOSE 5432`.

Comment: What do you get if you run ``oc describe service/my_app``? It is the service object you want to be looking at. Either way, the port will not be exposed outside of the OpenShift cluster by default if that is what you are expecting.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton No `svc` resource has been created by this `oc new-app` (that seems to be part of the problem). Only `is`, `bc`, `dc`, and `pod`. And yes, a port exposed inside the cluster would be enough at this stage.

Comment: Was ``oc new-app`` run using a template, or by deploying an image? If deploying from an image, or using a Source-to-Image (S2I) builder, a service would be created for you. Thus it suggests you deployed from a template which hasn't included the service object one would expect. If the deployment config defines the ports as it should, you can run ``oc expose dc/my_app`` to create the service. To better understand, provide the full ``oc new-app`` command you ran.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I have updated the Q with the actual `oc new-app` command. Thanks for your help. I guess what I might do next is use a standard (say, PostgreSQL) Docker image instead, and see how that goes.

Comment: Why don't you use the PostgreSQL image that comes with OpenShift? It will run correctly as non root user, auto configure things for you so you don't have to work it out, and most important sets the deployment strategy to Recreate. The default Rolling strategy shouldn't be used with databases. Try: ``oc new-app --template postgresql-persistent``.

Comment: If starting out with OpenShift, you may want to read the three free eBooks you can find linked at bottom of https://help.openshift.com/

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes, I can see how that will likely work (and so would exposing the port explicitly). The reason I'm asking is that the particular route I've chosen for now (partly for learning how the sausage is made) does not lead to the port being exposed, although the cited documentation  seems to suggest the opposite.

Comment: If you run your ``oc new-app`` command but add the options ``--dry-run -o json``, does the JSON it produces show a ``Service`` object? In the ``DeploymentConfig`` what does it show for the ``ports`` definition in the container?

Comment: Now the service shows up with `PORT(S) 5432/TCP` in `oc get all` (and it also shows up in the JSON output). Not sure what made the difference, probably some previous error of mine. So mystery seems solved. Thank you very (!) much for your persisting assinstance. If you want to write up a generic answer (in terms of debugging in a situation like this by inspecting JSON output, etc.) I shall accept it. Otherwise I shall delete this question.

Comment: Please do not delete the question. That defeats the purpose of having StackOverflow as a record of such discussions. It is actions like that which just makes people who help say 'why bother'. That is, why help people if others just go and delete the discussion. Means it was all a waste of time as doesn't benefit others in future who find it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Agreed, but then there should be some sort of answer to the question, so it does not raise further unwarranted attention. Do you prefer if I post one myself?

Comment: You are quite welcome to post one since you understand best what issues/result was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the problem "suddenly" went away and `oc new-app` now indeed exposes the port (as the documentation says). I am  so far using a trivial `Dockerfile` such as this

```
FROM debian:stretch
EXPOSE 5432

COPY start.sh /usr/local/bin/start.sh
CMD ["start.sh"]
```

where `startup.sh` calls `sleep infinity`. In terms of explanation, I can only guess that I had made some secondary and transient error that caused an interference.

Here are lessons learned while attempting to diagnose and solve the issue (big thanks to @GrahamDumpleton):

- If all goes well with `oc new-app`, `oc get all` should indicate port `5432/TCP` for resource  `svc/my_app` and should also list new OpenShift (and Kubernetes) resources of types `deploymentconfigs`, `buildconfigs`, `builds`, `imagestreams` , `po`, and `rc`.
- This automatic mechanism exposes the port only inside the
  cluster, i.e. `svc/my_app` has (and listens on) a cluster-IP (not: external-IP).
- Additional arguments `--dry-run -output json` cause `oc new-app` to conduct a dry-run and print an exact description (in JSON format) of what resources it would normally create.