# Unable to expose a created service in openshift

Tags: docker, proxy, openshift

I have created a new app using docker image. The new app is created but when I tried to expose the service. It is return service not found. Thoug I have checked the ouput of

```
oc status -v
```

It is showing the name of the service which is running. But I am unable to expose the service outside the cluster. I am on windows 10 using powershell.

Also When I up a cluster it shows me a wraning stating that my coker is using the proxy but I have not defined any proxy for windows. The documentation to set proxy in openshift is for linux.

The details of my cluster:

[image]

Comment: What command and arguments did you use to create the new app? What command did you use to expose the service? What do you get for ``oc get services`` and ``oc get routes``?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I have added a snapshot of my error and the result of status and  services. Thanks in advance. I am really stuck from 2 days. It is my first time working with openshift.

Comment: If the docker image not defined EXPOSE directive during build, the `Service` would not create. Refer [“oc new-app” does not expose port altough the input image does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748688/oc-new-app-does-not-expose-port-altough-the-input-image-does) for details.